# MySQL Error 1064 when adding foreign key with MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

So I have an error, when I want to add a foreign key. I added the foreign key in MySQL Workbench with an EER Diagram Model. The lines workbench tries to add are:`

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `barberDB` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 ;
USE `barberDB` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `barberDB`.`BARBER`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `barberDB`.`BARBER` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `barberDB`.`CUSTOMER`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `barberDB`.`CUSTOMER` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `isHaircut` INT NULL,
  `isBeard` INT NULL,
  `isEyebrows` INT NULL,
  `BARBER_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  INDEX `fk_CUSTOMER_BARBER_idx` (`BARBER_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_CUSTOMER_BARBER`
    FOREIGN KEY (`BARBER_ID`)
    REFERENCES `barberDB`.`BARBER` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

The error I get is:

```
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_CUSTOMER_BARBER`
    FOREIGN KEY (`BARBER_ID`)
    REF' at line 12
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `barberDB`.`CUSTOMER`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `barberDB`.`CUSTOMER` (
          `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
          `isHaircut` INT NULL,
          `isBeard` INT NULL,
          `isEyebrows` INT NULL,
          `BARBER_ID` INT NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
          INDEX `fk_CUSTOMER_BARBER_idx` (`BARBER_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_CUSTOMER_BARBER`
            FOREIGN KEY (`BARBER_ID`)
            REFERENCES `barberDB`.`BARBER` (`ID`)
            ON DELETE CASCADE
            ON UPDATE CASCADE)
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 6 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

I searched for solutions and find that parenthesis are important or backticks, but since the code is created by the tool, it seems correct to me. 
What could cause the error?

Comment: Your MySQL version doesn't understand the `VISIBLE` keyword - which is introduced in MySQL 8. Just remove it.

Comment: when I check the version of mysql via 'mysql -V' it says 'mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.23, for Linux (armv7l) using  EditLine wrapper
' So it should be ok or not?

Comment: Your version is 5.7.23. It doesn't support index visibility.

Comment: @BurakTopuz . . . I would add that explicitly declaring an index as `visible` is unnecessary; indexes are visible by default.  I would only play with index visibility as part of testing the feasibility of removing one or more indexes from an existing system.

Comment: ok, there are no errors after deleting VISIBLE thanks!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

For anyone looking this, in the EER Diagram Model window you can set wich MySQL version want use to generate SQL script. Go to Edit, Preferences, then Modeling section, MySQL and set your custom MySQL version.

Answer (score 10):

Check Your MySQL version and update it in:

Preferences -> Modeling -> MySQL -> Default Target MySQL Version

My MySQL version is 5.7.21.

Answer (score 4):

In MySQL Workbench, when you are connected to a server, click on "Server" from main menu and then "Server Status".

With "Version: X.X" go to your EER Diagram tag, click on "Edit" from main menu and "preferences", then in Modeling section "MySQL" set your custom MySQL version taked before.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @imnothuman

In **MacOS** MySQL Workbench version, you can set the MySQL script version here:

From opened EER Diagram:
Model -> Model Options.
MySQL tab.
Uncheck "Use defaults from global settings".
Set version in "Target MySQL Version" input.

Answer (score 0):

it can be for the current version of mysql against the default version workbench:

Change default targe version mysql in workbench:

references -> Modeling -> MySQL -> Default Target MySQL Version

Answer (score -1):

i was using mysql version 5.5.62 .

commenting of the line 
`INDEX 'fk_CUSTOMER_BARBER_idx' ('BARBER_ID' ASC) VISIBLE,` 
did worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the VISIBLE keyword and run the code if its below mysql 5.7