# Erro 1064 mysql erro

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
  CONSTRAINT fk_telefone_usuario
    FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id)
    REFERENCE' at line 12
SQL Code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dashboard_jr.telefone (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ddd INT(2) NOT NULL,
  telefone INT(9) NOT NULL,
  operadora VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  tipo ENUM('f', 'm') NOT NULL,
  status ENUM('a', 'i') NOT NULL,
  usuario_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  created DATETIME NOT NULL,
  modified DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  INDEX fk_telefone_usuario_idx (usuario_id ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT fk_telefone_usuario
    FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id)
    REFERENCES dashboard_jr.usuario (id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Comment: (Your) MariaDB doesn't support `VISIBLE`. set the "Default Target MySQL Version" to 5.7 - see: [mysql-workbench-error-in-query-1064-syntax-error-near-visible-at-line-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52785125/mysql-workbench-error-in-query-1064-syntax-error-near-visible-at-line-1)

Comment: [mysql-error-1064-when-adding-foreign-key-with-mysql-workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51917812/mysql-error-1064-when-adding-foreign-key-with-mysql-workbench)

Comment: Cool, I just took VISIBLE and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

The komma immediately before CONSTRAINT

Comment: I am generating by mysql_workbench, when I shoot the comma before CONSTRAINT, but the error remains.

Comment: The comma is where it should be.

Comment: Cool, I just took VISIBLE and it worked!