# Trouble to add a foreign key at table

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-workbench

I have a table called `model_agricultural_machine` with this command, I'm using MariaDB

```
CREATE TABLE `autoparanaiba`.`model_agricultural_machine` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `description` VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
  `brand_agricultural_machine_id` TINYINT(5) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_modelXbrand_idx` (`brand_agricultural_machine_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_modelXbrand`
    FOREIGN KEY (`brand_agricultural_machine_id`)
    REFERENCES `autoparanaiba`.`brand_agricultural_machine` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

And when I run this command, appears this error.

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
CREATE TABLE `autoparanaiba`.`model_agricultural_machine` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `description` VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
  `brand_agricultural_machine_id` TINYINT(5) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_modelXbrand_idx` (`brand_agricultural_machine_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_modelXbrand`
    FOREIGN KEY (`brand_agricultural_machine_id`)
    REFERENCES `autoparanaiba`.`brand_agricultural_machine` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
  CONSTRAINT `fk_modelXbrand`
    FOREIGN KEY (`brand_agricultural_machine_id`)' at line 6
SQL Statement:
CREATE TABLE `autoparanaiba`.`model_agricultural_machine` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `description` VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
  `brand_agricultural_machine_id` TINYINT(5) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_modelXbrand_idx` (`brand_agricultural_machine_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_modelXbrand`
    FOREIGN KEY (`brand_agricultural_machine_id`)
    REFERENCES `autoparanaiba`.`brand_agricultural_machine` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

I saw this link [MySQL Error 1064 when adding foreign key with MySQL Workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51917812/mysql-error-1064-when-adding-foreign-key-with-mysql-workbench)
So I saw at Workbench was `8.0.17` I runned this command to see the MySQL Version

```
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

And I changed at MySQL Workbench but didn't nothing and appears the same error.

Comment: Do you still get that error if you remove the keyword VISIBLE from INDEX?

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson I got. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by removing at the index where there are about `ASC VISIBLE`.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I removed "VISIBLE" from the generated SQL.